# Stellar horizon shows "Still Ingesting" after 5 days

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, ledger, validators

I am running stellar-horizon on ec2 server

I cloned stellar-core from `git clone https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core.git` and installed it. I installed horizon from the [package manager](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/run-api-server/installing#package-manager) with the following [SDF repository](https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/docs/adding-the-sdf-stable-repository-to-your-system.md#adding-the-sdf-stable-repository-to-your-system).

Then I created four nodes on same servers: `node01, node02, node03, node04` with `stellar-core.cfg`. Note that I am using `s3 bucket` for history.
Then I ran these 2 command for each folder:

1. `stellar-core new-db`
2. `stellar-core --conf stellar-core.cfg new-hist s4`
   Then I ran services for all four nodes.

Then I ran the following commands for horizon

1. `init db` : stellar-horizon db init --db-url="postgresql://user_horizon:password@localhost:5432/stellar_horizon_db"
2. `ingest` : stellar-horizon ingest init-genesis-state  --db-url="postgresql://user_horizon:password@localhost:5432/stellar_horizon_db"  --network-passphrase "STELLAR PWD; AUG 2023" --history-archive-urls "http://historys3.domain.com"
3. `run` : /usr/bin/stellar-horizon --db-url="postgresql://user_horizon:password@localhost:5432/stellar_horizon_db" --stellar-core-db-url="postgresql://dbname=stellar_node01_db host=localhost user=user_stellar password=password" --stellar-core-url="http://127.0.0.1:11336" --port 4000 --network-passphrase "STELLAR PWD; AUG 2023" --stellar-core-binary-path="/usr/local/bin/stellar-core" --captive-core-config-path "/etc/default/stellar-captive-core-stub.toml" --history-archive-urls "http://historys3.domain.com"

All nodes are synced and both node and horizon logs don't show any errors. It creates new folders in ledgers every 10-15 min on s3 bucket.

**Info for one node**

```
{
   "info" : {
      "build" : "quarkslab-core-dirty",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 3,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 100000000,
         "closeTime" : 1693743499,
         "hash" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
         "num" : 65783,
         "version" : 0
      },
      "network" : "STELLAR PWD; AUG 2023",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 3,
         "pending_count" : 0
      },
      "protocol_version" : 19,
      "quorum" : {
         "node" : "node02",
         "qset" : {
            "agree" : 4,
            "cost" : 12336,
            "delayed" : 0,
            "disagree" : 0,
            "fail_at" : 2,
            "hash" : "xxxxxx",
            "lag_ms" : 12,
            "ledger" : 65782,
            "missing" : 0,
            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",
            "validated" : true
         },
         "transitive" : {
            "critical" : null,
            "intersection" : true,
            "last_check_ledger" : 16017,
            "node_count" : 4
         }
      },
      "startedOn" : "2023-08-28T12:16:40Z",
      "state" : "Synced!"
   }
}
```

**Horizon Logs**

```
level=info msg="Ledger: Close of ledger 135 buffered. mSyncingLedgers has 5 ledgers" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="History: Waiting for trigger ledger: 135/193, ETA: 290s" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="Herder: Quorum information for 134 : {\"agree\":4,\"cost\":16384,\"delayed\":0,\"disagree\":0,\"fail_at\":2,\"hash\":\"741df9\",\"lag_ms\":2,\"ledger\":134,\"missing\":0,\"phase\":\"EXTERNALIZE\"}" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="Ledger: Got consensus: [seq=136, prev=2da884, txs=0, ops=0, sv: [ SIGNED@node04 txH: g78906, ct: 1693744101, upgrades: [ ] ]]" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="Ledger: Close of ledger 136 buffered. mSyncingLedgers has 6 ledgers" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="History: Waiting for trigger ledger: 136/193, ETA: 285s" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="Herder: Quorum information for 135 : {\"agree\":4,\"cost\":16384,\"delayed\":0,\"disagree\":0,\"fail_at\":2,\"hash\":\"741df9\",\"lag_ms\":2,\"ledger\":135,\"missing\":0,\"phase\":\"EXTERNALIZE\"}" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="Ledger: Got consensus: [seq=137, prev=a2734b, txs=0, ops=0, sv: [ SIGNED@node02 txH: 26940d, ct: 1693744106, upgrades: [ ] ]]" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
level=info msg="Ledger: Close of ledger 137 buffered. mSyncingLedgers has 7 ledgers" pid=741289 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
```

**Issue**
The services are running since the last 5 days, but I am still getting "Still Ingesting" when I run `curl http://localhost:4000/paths`.